# email and password. if correct go to url

Tags: html

Does anyone know how to make my login form work without PHP
such that if I enter a specific email and password it will go to a specific page? So basically it would function as a login page.

Please help

This is my code:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
     <div class="form-container sign-up-container">

     </div>
     <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
         <form action="#">
             <h1>Login</h1>

             <span>Login with your education Account</span>
             <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
             <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
             <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
             <button>Sign In</button> 
         </form>    
     </div>
     <div class="overlay-container">
         <div class="overlay">
             <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">

             </div> 
             <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                <h1 style="color:white;">Department of Education</h1> <br>
                <img src="doe-logo-white.png"> 

                 <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>

             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Without a back-end, how will your website know whether the email / password combination is correct? I suppose you could hardcode the password on the client side, but anyone could then see the password in the source, defeating the purpose of having one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, this question seems too broad for the site.  There are many different technologies and manners in which a login could be achieved.  Ultimately you'll need to submit the user/password to the backend _somehow_, and then have the backend redirect the user into the logged in application or prompt them that the user/pw combo was incorrect or that something else went wrong.  To give any answer more detailed that that would require knowing your whole stack and architecting the whole solution-- certainly there are better resources online for that.